# Save option disabled when scaling azure cosmos database throughput

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have Azure Cosmos DB account which has been provisioned with "Provisioned throughput" capacity mode. Currently we have less usage on the resources hence trying to reduce the RU's database. I go to My Azure Cosmos DB account -> Data Explorer -> Select the instance -> Scale & Setting. I tried to reduced the RU's to lower range but somehow "Save" option is disable.

I have "owner" privilege's for entire subscription however Save option is disabled. I am trying to lower the RU from 8000 to 800 however i am unable to save it. Is this because of RBAC issue or is it because of the fact that i created my account beginning in such a way that i wont be able to scale throughput? Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have at least 1000 RU/s provisioned for autoscale. It was 4000 RU/s until [just recently](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availability-azure-cosmos-db-autoscale-rus-entry-point-is-4x-lower/).

> The entry point for autoscale maximum throughput Tmax starts at 1000 RU/s, which scales between 100 - 1000 RU/s. You can set Tmax in increments of 1000 RU/s and change the value at any time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/provision-throughput-autoscale#how-autoscale-provisioned-throughput-works

Comment: Thanks for the speedy update. I was able to play with the values.. Under autoplay, i kept value as 1999, unable to see Save option. Only when i enter numbers more than 2000 then Save option appears.. any thoughts?

Comment: @Surendar As it says, it needs to be an increment of 1000, so 1000/2000/3000/4000/...